# Characters to force sql sort to the end

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have the following values:

```
is_flagged    name
0             Titanic
1             Avatar
0             Jesse
0             トゥー・フォー・ザ・マネー (字幕版)
```

I want to sort first by is_flagged, then by name. For various reasons, I need to include the sort in one statement.

How would I put the ones where `is_flagged`=0 to the very end (beyond any character). So far I have:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN is_flagged IS TRUE THEN name else 'ZZZ' END
```

Basically, how do I use characters (what is now 'ZZZ') to go to the very end. Please note that **I'm not looking for this answer**:

```
ORDER BY is_flagged DESC, name ASC
```

Comment: *Why* are you not looking for that answer? What is wrong with using the easiest/best answer?

Comment: I have various other sorts in the sql query and I need to sort one way when is_flagged=True and another way when is_flagged=False.

Comment: Then ask how to do that. Your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454). --- [Answer by Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46983170/5221149) has given you a good solution, but it might not be the *right* solution for your actual problem.

Comment: Regardless of the merits of the question, a *statement* is not an *expression*.  You want a single *expression*, not *statement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy hack is to concatinate the columns you want to sort by:

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(CASE is_flagged WHEN 0 THEN 'z' ELSE 'a' END, name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach. Is "z" the lowest character? What about japanese or some other unicode characters, etc.

Comment: @David542 the ordering between `z` and any Japanese character is inconsequential - either a `z` or an `a` is prepended to the name (depending on the value of `is_flagged`), and `a` comes before `z`. Between the rows with the same `is_flagged` values, the sorting is effectively done according to the names.

Comment: Got it -- thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY is_flagged DESC
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 1 THEN sortAvalue1 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 1 THEN sortAvalue2 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 1 THEN sortAvalue3 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 1 THEN sortAvalue4 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 0 THEN sortBvalue1 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 0 THEN sortBvalue2 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 0 THEN sortBvalue3 ELSE NULL END
, CASE WHEN is_flagged = 0 THEN sortBvalue4 ELSE NULL END
```

This should work, even when the is_flagged values are secondarily sorted by completely different data types.

If the sort criteria do share types, they can be merged like so `CASE WHEN is_flagged = 1 THEN sortAvalue1 ELSE sortBvalue1 END`; but in my experience that makes such queries a little harder to maintain.